# DTS package to publish from MSSQL 2000 to 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a number of DTS packages set up that publish from our local SQL Server 2000 database to a SQL Server 2005 database on our live web server (these were originally set up in Enterprise Manager). We've had to migrate to a new live host which is using SQL Server 2008, but we still need to publish from the MSSQL 2000 database. Can I still publish using these packages?

Additionally this new host does not have MSSQL 2008 Integration Services installed, and are not able to install this, so I cannot use the package update wizard in SQL Server Management Studio.

How is it possible to execute these DTS packages seeing as it seems Enterprise Manager won't allow connections to SQL Server 2008 databases?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this Microsoft SQL Server support article:

**[Support for Data Transformation Services (DTS) in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx)**

> Although SQL Server 2000 Data
>   Transformation Services (DTS) is
>   deprecated, SQL Server 2008 provides
>   optional 32-bit management, run-time,
>   and design-time support for packages
>   that were created by using the DTS
>   tools and object model. (For more
>   information about the deprecation of
>   DTS, see  Data Transformation Services
>   (DTS).)
>
> [...]
>
> Be aware that not all DTS functionality is supported in all circumstances. The following sections describe exactly what DTS functionality is supported in SQL Server 2008.